# Unable to Subtract CGFloats

Tags: ios, swift, geometry, cgrect, cgfloat

I'm trying to incorporate code from the [Keyboard Management](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html) documentation produced by Apple into my app. So far I have been able to parse the Objective-C into Swift, but there is one line that I'm having problems with. Here it is in context (the last line is where the error occurs):

```
func keyboardWasShown(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    let info = aNotification.userInfo as NSDictionary!
    let kbSize = (info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue()

    let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize!.height, 0.0)
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets

    let aRect = view.frame
    aRect.size.height -= kbSize!.height //This line gives me trouble.
}
```

At that line, I get an error message that says "**Cannot invoke '-=' with an argument list of type '(CGFloat, CGFloat)'**". Are there any work arounds to solve this problem or is there anything I'm doing wrong?

---

NB: I have tried casting them both to floats, but get the error "**Cannot invoke 'init' with an argument list of type '($T4, $T9)'**". When I cast the as floats in different variables and then subtract them, I get the error "**Cannot invoke '-=' with an argument list of type '(Float, Float)'**".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please change `let aRect` to `var aRect`, a variable can be changed.

Comment: let is used to define constants and var to define variables.